# How Receipt Ref gets its value when a pos order is placed

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, pos

In odoo 8,there is a field named `Receipt Ref` (technical name `pos_referance`. I want to know about how this value is created.
For eg: If `pos_referance` is 27574-004-04-0003 , what does `27574` , `004` , `04` and `0003`stands for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This number is generated from the JavaScript file located at addons/point_of_sale/static/src/js/models.js

In this file you can find one model names "Order", inside this model one method is there which is responsible for this sequence. Please have a look below for that method.

```
generateUniqueId: function() {
       function zero_pad(num,size){
            var s = ""+num;
            while (s.length < size) {
                s = "0" + s;
            }
            return s;
        }
        return zero_pad(this.pos.pos_session.id,5) +'-'+
               zero_pad(this.pos.pos_session.login_number,3) +'-'+
               zero_pad(this.sequence_number,4);
},
```

Comment: `login_number` means.. ? And can you give a brief explaination on the above code.(I don't know js)   @Suhindra

Comment: login_number means a sequence number that is incremented each time a user resumes the pos session

Comment: `sequence_number` means .? Please help me on this also .. 
Thanks in Advance... @Suhindra

Comment: sequence_number = a session-unique sequence number for the order

Comment: Thanks Man.. @Suhindra